# R: extract part content from text file (e.g. sdf) according to certain pattern?

Tags: r

```
[A]
66 67  1  0  0  0  0
67 69  2  0  0  0  0
67 71  1  0  0  0  0
68 69  1  0  0  0  0
72 73  2  3  0  0  0
72 74  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <DRUGBANK_ID>
DB00035
> <ALOGPS_SOLUBILITY>
1.10e-01 g/l
$$$$

[B]
66 67  1  0  0  0  0
67 69  2  0  0  0  0
67 71  1  0  0  0  0
68 69  1  0  0  0  0
72 73  2  3  0  0  0
72 74  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <DRUGBANK_ID>
DB00036
> <ALOGPS_SOLUBILITY>
1.10e-01 g/l
$$$$

[C]
66 67  1  0  0  0  0
67 69  2  0  0  0  0
67 71  1  0  0  0  0
68 69  1  0  0  0  0
72 73  2  3  0  0  0
72 74  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <DRUGBANK_ID>
DB00039
> <ALOGPS_SOLUBILITY>
1.10e-02333
$$$$
```

I have such above sdf file, and I want to extract those lines which include DRUGBANK_ID=DB00035 and DB00039, that means I want to extract [A] and [C] contents. Each file ends with $$$$. In my sdf file includes more than 7000 such formats, what is the efficient method to extract my wanted pattern? Thank you.

```
[A]
66 67  1  0  0  0  0
67 69  2  0  0  0  0
67 71  1  0  0  0  0
68 69  1  0  0  0  0
72 73  2  3  0  0  0
72 74  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <DRUGBANK_ID>
DB00035
> <ALOGPS_SOLUBILITY>
1.10e-01 g/l
$$$$

[C]
66 67  1  0  0  0  0
67 69  2  0  0  0  0
67 71  1  0  0  0  0
68 69  1  0  0  0  0
72 73  2  3  0  0  0
72 74  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <DRUGBANK_ID>
DB00039
> <ALOGPS_SOLUBILITY>
1.10e-02333
$$$$
```

Comment: Probably makes more sense to use something like `sed` to do the filtering, otherwise in R you're stuck with reading the entire file in and filtering out the required entries (which may be OK for you, depending on how huge the file is. If you had say a 100MB file to filter through you wouldn't want to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the lines and create a grouping variable, `g.all`, having a component for each line of the file. That is, it is 1 for each line of the first group, 2 for each line of the second group and so on.  Determine which group each of the desired strings are in giving `g.ok` and then extract all lines from those groups:

```
L <- readLines("myfile")
g.all <- cumsum(grepl("^\\[", L))
g.ok <- g.all[grep("DB00035|DB00039", L)]
L[g.all %in% g.ok]
```

**ADDED** To use the $$$$ as the marker replace the second line with:

```
g.all <- rev(cumsum(grepl("$$$$", rev(L), fixed = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck. it works for my question. but "^\\[" is not the only marks in my big sdf file. On the contrary, \\$$$$ is the only mark, can you use \\$$$$ to get the same answer? Thanks.

Comment: Have added a variation for using $$$$