# R: OR regular express max length is 2555? it is error when the length of OR(|) 2556

Tags: r

The max length of regular expression OR(|) is 2555?

```
dat <- paste("DB", 1:10000, sep="")

pat <- dat[1:2555]
pat <- paste("^", pat, "$", sep = "")
pat <- paste(pat, collapse = "|")

system.time({
  (g.ok <- grep(pattern = pat, x = dat))
})
```

when pat <- dat[1:2555], it works, but when pat <- dat[1:2556], it will give the error. Can you help me explain the reason?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     
>
```

Comment: What is the exact error text?

Comment: I suspect it has more to do with the number of characters in the pattern; it works with "D" instead of "DB" with 2556 and not with "DBX" with 2555.  Seriously, though, what's the point? A pattern that long seems to defeat the purpose of a regex. (And in this simple case, just use `%in%`!)

Comment: error text like this.   Error in grep(pattern = pat, x = dat) : 
  invalid regular expression '^DB1$|^DB2$|^DB3$|^DB4$|^DB5$|^DB6$|
Timing stopped at: 0 0 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) uses tcl regular expressions making it independent of R and those can handle 2556.   Using `dat` from the question:

```
pat <- dat[1:2556]
pat <- paste0("^", pat, "$")
pat <- paste(pat, collapse = "|")

library(gsubfn)
out <- Filter(nchar, strapplyc(dat, pat, simplify = c))
length(out)
## [1] 2556
```

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck. it works. but can strapplyc get the positions like those obtained by grep?   Just like your previous help for me. Here just the regular expression have more 5000.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073168/r-extract-part-content-from-text-file-e-g-sdf-according-to-certain-pattern/23074602?noredirect=1#comment35302257_23074602

Comment: That is not its purpose but you could try: `which(nchar(strapplyc(dat, pat, simplify = c)) > 0)` .

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck.

Answer (score 4):

The ["stringi" package](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/) seems to be able to handle this OK.

Looking at your example, I guess you would want something like:

```
library(stringi)
stri_detect_regex(dat, pat)          ## returns a logical vector
which(stri_detect_regex(dat, pat))   ## wrap with `which` to get positions
```

It also seems to be fast for this particular problem:

```
system.time(out1 <- which(nchar(strapplyc(dat, pat, simplify = c)) > 0))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   5.245   0.331   5.586 
system.time(out2 <- which(stri_detect_regex(dat, pat)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.698   0.000   0.687 
identical(out1, out2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @Ananda Mahto. It is much faster.

Comment: I try it to my sdf file. It works faster. Thanks all for your help.